# QGIS 3 Atlas: text box expression for automatically displaying names of all visible features?

Tags: qgis-3, print-composer, expression, atlas

I am currently working with the QGIS (3.6) map composer using the atlas tool; it's quite handy, but I've come across a small problem and I'm wondering if there is a solution to this.

The coverage layer is a multi-polygon layer with different survey fields (see image)

[image]

I would like to add a text box to the map layout automatically displaying the name of the current feature (in the centre), **as well as the names of the other visible features** in the map layout. For example, the text could read "map showing the outlines of field_a, field_b, field_c etc."

I know that I can use the "expression"-function for obtaining the name of the current feature, but is there also an expression to obtain all of the other ones?

Comment: So... you want labels?

Comment: no, the text box in the lower left corner should contain the names of all the outlined fields in the map layout

Comment: for example, I can insert the expression [%"Name"%] in the text field, but it will only give me the name of the current feature; I would like to know if there is an expression to get the names of all features

Comment: Yeah, but why go through that trouble, when you can use labels?

Comment: it's not displayed but the polygones actually outline raster fields and I don't want to use labes as they would cover some raster cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an [attribute table](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/composer_items/composer_attribute_table.html) to the layout.

In the item properties tab, choose the option to "show only features within a map."

Click the "Attributes" button to open a dialogue that lets you choose which columns to display - turn off all the columns except "Name". In this dialogue you can also edit the displayed column name.

This should give you a list of the Names of all the features in your chosen layer on the current map.

If you have multiple layers, add another table for each layer.